# calling a second view in iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to adapt an existing application to an iPad app.  The application has a main view that calls View2 that is in "View2.xib".  Everything has been working well, until I entered the following:

```
if(!view2Controller)
{
view2Controller = [[View2Controller alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"View2"];
}
[view2Controller showWindow:self];
```

This works in my original Cocoa program, but in the iPad application it is currently returning a warning: "Thread1: Program received signal "SIGBRT"  While working with it, I've also received a message Method -initWithWindowNibName not found. 
Similarly, I have the same problem with the method showWindow.

I wonder how it is that this problem shows up when I try to convert it to an iPad app.
I've run out of ideas to check and would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change it to the following

```
if(!view2Controller)
{
     view2Controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil]
}

//If you are in a view controller use
[self presentModalViewController:view2Controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped, It runs without error, now, but isn't showing View2.  Do you suppose it's now a connection problem on the View2Controller side?

Comment: do you have a View2.xib, if yes, does it contain a view controller?

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, it does.  I studied it some more and found that it needed a view2Controller removeFromSuperview method.  Now it is working properly.  I sincerely appreciate your help.